# Java JTable can't load from file after editing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm making a Java program - a database tourism agency. I have made where it loads information from file into table, you can add new information and it saves it, you can calculate average price, you can edit information in table and it saves it into file, but this is the point where I get the problem.

- When I edit cell, it edits the information in .txt file but when I try to load the file again after editing it just deletes everything in file.

Table listener when I edit table.

```
    jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                try {
                    saveTable();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Save table function

```
     public void saveTable()throws Exception
     {

    StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer();
    TableModel tModel = jTable1.getModel();
    for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < jTable1.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            Object cellValue = tModel.getValueAt(row, col) + ", ";
            fileContent.append(cellValue);
        }
        fileContent.append("\n");
    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("/home/nauris/Desktop/mydata.txt"));
    fileWriter.write(fileContent.toString());
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
    }
```

Load table function

```
public void loadTable()throws Exception
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/nauris/Desktop/mydata.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null ) {
            model.addRow(line.split(", "));
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- Second thing is, I need to search for rows where the price is lower then I have put in my text field.

  ```
      JTextField searchField = new JTextField();

      searchField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 24));
      buttonPanel.add(searchField, gbc);

      JButton searchButton = new JButton("Atrast");
      buttonPanel.add(searchButton, gbc);

      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

      searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              int text = Integer.parseInt(searchField.getText());
              if (String.valueOf(text) == null) {
                  //sorter.setRowFilter(null);
              } else {
                  int rowsCount = jTable1.getRowCount();
                  int value= 0;
                  for(int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++){
                      value = Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                      if(value<text) {
                          model.removeRow(i);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      });
  ```

But it gives me error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
```

Comment: where is the IndexOutOfBoundsException being thrown?

Comment: You get the `rowCount` of the `JTable`, but then you delete rows from the model in a loop `model.removeRow(i);`, this means that the row count has now changed...

Comment: @JoopEggen That could cause you to skip rows (as `index` will still be incremented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code give above you are trying to filter the rows based on the search value.It would be better if you use a RowFilter instead of removing the rows from the model.

```
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
        RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> rf = RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.BEFORE, searchValue, 0);
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java

**Edit 12-May**

I have given the complete code listing. It works as you expect.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testtable;

import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private DefaultTableModel model = null;

    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form MyFrame
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{
            "Name", "age", "salary"
        });
        jTable1.setModel(model);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Beniton", 34, 10000});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Joema", 33, 10000});
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
        jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        searchBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("Search");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        searchBox.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 20));
        searchBox.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 20));
        searchBox.setName("searchField"); // NOI18N
        searchBox.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 20));
        searchBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                searchBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        getContentPane().add(searchBox, gridBagConstraints);
        searchBox.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void searchBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if (searchBox.getText().length() > 0) {
            Integer value = Integer.parseInt(searchBox.getText());
            // Checking the age as Index is 1
            RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> rf = RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.BEFORE, value, 1);
            sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
        } else {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        }
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField searchBox;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I have added this to the code, but nothing happens

`searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  int searchValue = Integer.parseInt(searchField.getText());
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
        try {
   RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> rf = RowFilter.numberFilter(RowFilter.ComparisonType.BEFORE, searchValue, 0);
   sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
  } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
   return;
  }
 }
});`

Comment: @MrEnergy I have edited the answer to show complete code listing.